# Design issue with JPA inheritance, Spring Roo and Spring Data JPA

Tags: inheritance, jpa, spring-roo, spring-data-jpa

I am currently working on a Spring Roo/JPA application and I recently switched to a domain model **based upon JPA inheritance**. To sum up my domain model, I have an abstract `Member` entity that is subclassed by two entities: `Male` and `Female`.

In all of my Spring MVC controllers, I would like to avoid always injecting two service dependencies (one that would deal with `Male` entities and the other with `Female` entities). I'd rather have one `MemberService` service (together with a corresponding `MemberRepository`) that would return either a `Male` instance or a `Female` instance.

Is the above possible using Spring Roo annotations such as this one:

- `@RooService(domainTypes = { Member.class })` or that one:
- `@RooJpaRepository(domainType = Member.class)` ?

For instance, will this `Member findByEmail(String email);` return an object that I can ***cast*** to either the `Female` or `Male` type?

**More generally, what are the best practices to deal with entity inheritance at the level of Spring controllers and Spring services?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to provide a repository for Male and another for Female
using:

```
repository jpa --interface ~.repository.MaleRepository --entity ~.domain.Male
repository jpa --interface ~.repository.FemaleRepository --entity ~.domain.Female
```

you get:

```
@RooJpaRepository(domainType = Female.class)
public interface FemaleRepository {
}

@RooJpaRepository(domainType = Male.class)
public interface MaleRepository {
}
```

then you create the service layer for the application for these models (a service for each model)

```
service --interface ~.service.MaleService --entity ~.domain.Male
service --interface ~.service.FamaleService --entity ~.domain.Female
```

and then you get:

```
@RooService(domainTypes = { Male.class })
public interface MaleService {
}

@RooService(domainTypes = { Female.class })
public interface FemaleService {
}
```

This is assuming that your Male and Female objects have different responsibility so is needed to separate it in different classes, by the name you gave them (Male and Female) i think they don't, but i don't know your business logic and of course this is just an example (but how faithful is to your real problem?).

The idea of inheritance is not only to share common functionality to "is-a" descendants but preserve the sense of the OO logic, when i say that i mean, in this case for example, you could resolve the problem with an attribute called sex if Male and Female have the same attributes; if this is not the case then wont be painful to create different repositories and services for those specialized objects.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. The trouble with this solution is that I need two services (Male and Female) in each of the controller that deals with Male and Female instances. Furthermore my controller code becames ugly with conditional logic to check whether I need to use one or the other of the services...

Comment: I suspect that Female and Male have similar responsibility in your business since you want to use both in the same controller, i think your solution is to write a class Member with sex a attribute...

Comment: @balteo I think Carlos is asking you to rethink whether you need inheritance or not. If you use the sex attribute you don't need inheritance. If you're building a dating app, for example, and there is a significant difference between the sexes then maybe inheritance is relevant